# how to distribute different version of app based on location of user on play store

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-play

I have to use different instances of firebase firestore. But  firebase doesn't allow that. So now I am planning to use different projects for different regions. But I am unable to find information about distribution of different app version based on country of user. Any advice would be very helpful to me.
Btw thanks in advance.

Comment: why not provide multiple versions for each region you want covered and let users choose themselves? (Instead of a single version that auto-adjusts itself based on region)

Comment: for example `my-app-europe`, `my-app-asia`, .. and let users download the app version mathing their region, not try to do this automaticaly, very simple

Comment: even amazon cloud has users choose the region of interest and it is not auto-adjusted

Comment: but wouldn't it require me to  publish multiple version of same app

Comment: it's not something I want

Comment: yes you publish multiple versions of the same app from exactly same codebase, codebase DOES NOT change, only a couple of config parameters, extraneous to the codebase itself, so not really a problem